# Минимальная глубина цвета

Tags: графика

Какая  минимальная  глубина  цвета  требуется  для  цифрового 
представления картинки, состоящей из чѐрных, серых и белых точек?

Comment: @shnygagagagaga, переформулируем вопрос. Согласно условию пиксель может находиться в трех различных состояниях. Сколько минимум бит нужно, чтобы закодировать 3 различных состояния? Подсказка: 3 бита могут кодировать до 2 в степени 3, т.е. 8 состояний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточните: как много оттенков серого?

Наглядно разобраться помог бы Photoshop: сделайте в нем Save for Web, выберите режим Grayscale, формат GIF. И посмотрите, как отличаются варианты с 4, 16 и 256 цветами. Каждый, в принципе, имеет право быть:

[image: screenshot диалога фотошопа]

Наиболее распостраненный вариант — кодировать один канал цвета 8-ю битами (2^8 = 256 значений). Однако, если ваш вопрос трактовать буквально, т.е. только три цвета: черный, 50% серый и белый, других нет, то достаточно 2 бит (макс. 4 цвета).